# Writing a Macro in Excel to data log

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help,

I am trying to write a Macro in Excel to log information coming in to excel via a PLC.

I have a row of data I am wanting to shift down a row when a Trigger cell goes from 0 > 1.

Any subsequent trigger moves the row down again and inserts newly captured data above. etc etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The function to append to a log just needs to determine the last row used and add new data after that.  You can replace fName with the PLC IP/address (if using more than one) or any other originating resource name.  You can combine the LastRow code but I use it in many other routines too so I made it a standalone function.

In my functions I just send messages to the recorder, like this:

```
RecordLog ftpFileReceived, ftpStatus
```

And here's the functions:

```
Sub RecordLog(fName As String, Status As String)
    Const F = "Import_Log"
    LR = LastRow(F, "A")
    Worksheets(F).Range("A" & LR + 1).Formula = Now()
    Worksheets(F).Range("B" & LR + 1).Formula = fName
    Worksheets(F).Range("C" & LR + 1).Formula = Status
End Sub
Function LastRow(Tabname As String, Col As String) As Long
    With Worksheets(Tabname)
       LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
   End With
End Function
```

Triggering this from an input logged from your PLC is activated through the worksheet function SelectionChange.  Code has to be put in the module for the spreadsheet you are monitoring.

If the PLC is generating all the updates and you don't have to worry about what cell was updated, this will record all the new values:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    RecordLog "PLC", "Value: " & Target
End Sub
```

If your spreadsheet is updated through means other than the PLC and you only want to log the PLC changes, you can record only updates to a specific cell in the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static LastValue As Variant
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value <> LastValue Then
        LastValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
        RecordLog "PLC", "Value: " & LastValue
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes each PLC value would be different and that's not always the case so you would need to tinker with that part a bit.